# How to use CTRL+HOME in the terminal?

Tags: bash, xubuntu, shortcut-keys, emacs

When I use emacs in graphic mode, I can go to the beginning of the buffer with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd>.

When in bash, emacs won't recognize the combination and only sees the <kbd>Home</kbd>.

I checked [like here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18242703/776515) and, in graphic mode I get `<C-home>`, but in bash I get `<home>`.

**How do I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd> in emacs in bash?**
(or any terminal: checked with `guake` too)

---

**Edit**

After some info from @steeldriver, I did the following test: Run `$ hexdump -C` followed by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd> with the following results so far:

- xfce4-terminal 0.6.3: `^[OH`
- Guake! 0.4.4: `^[OH`
- XTerm(297): `^[[1;5H`

In xfce-terminal I changed the character encoding (Preferences\Advanced), but does not seem to work.

Comment: I'm confused - are you talking about using readline's emacs editing mode in the bash shell, or about using emacs itself in a terminal (`emacs -nw`)?

Comment: @steeldriver `emacs -nw`

Comment: OK so some google-fu suggests this is a "feature" of gnome-terminal: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gnu.emacs.help/9wH00nz0k8o however the suggested work-around (unchecking the terminal's keyboard shorcuts) doesn't seem to work for me. You should see the expected behaviour in a plain xterm.

Comment: @steeldriver I didn't think of xterm. It works there indeed.  I am working on xubuntu, my terminals are xfce4-terminal 0.6.3 and Guake! 0.4.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is [a bug in libvte](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=600659). Is fixed in newer versions of libvte, but there are no plans to backport it to the versions currently in use.